# Change Azure Service Bus topic size

Tags: azure, size, servicebus

How I can change topic size in Service Bus?
I've tried change through REST API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj839740.aspx and in the Management Portal I've seen a new size. But I still getting error "The maximum entity size has been reached or exceeded for Topic: 'UISNOTIFICATION:TOPIC:ACCOUNTEVENTS'. Size of entity in bytes:1073742826, Max entity size in bytes: 1073741824..TrackingId:4b967ffc-b365-48b7-8e34-46fafca5f615_G13_B23,TimeStamp:10/4/2013 3:14:32 AM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexey, while some other properties on a Topic can be updated, size cannot be modified. Once a Topic is created the size is fixed to the size that was specified.

Comment: A later reply suggests this can now be changed, am I reading that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of a Topic is 5GB. Size can be modified in New Azure Portal.

[image]

Comment: Are we sure that just because the UI depicts a change is possible - it will actually work? Is there any caveats to increasing or DECREASING the size? Such as: decreasing will result in data loss? Or, the Topic needs to be brought off-line to change the size?